# Multiple users deploying to one cloudfoundry app

Tags: cloud-foundry

We have a cloudfoundry app and are pushing/updating using vmc. But how do we allow multiple users to be able to deploy this app ? Or do we just need to share login info with those who need ability to update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, sharing credentials is the only way to do it. However, in the new releases planned for Cloudfoundry.com, this issue will be addressed.

Check out the following blog entries;

http://blog.cloudfoundry.org/2012/06/20/heads-up-on-some-new-cloud-controller-features/

http://blog.cloudfoundry.org/2012/08/08/cc_ng_and_vmc/